# How do I create a view to add a new item to a list in a view model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

How do I create a view to add a new item to a list in a view model?

So I have view model with a list of objects in it (view model also has 1 other object in it). Basically the list will be comments (so I may have zero to x number of comments).

I am using VS 2010 (and I don't think it is the razor view engine?)

Here is my view, I want to have the option to add a new item to the list

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<JPROCommunitydataListings.ViewModels.dataWithCommentsViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    data Solution
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <p>data Description#    <%: Model.data.Description %></p>
    <p>data ParameterID#    <%: Model.data.ParameterID %></p>
    <%--<h2>dataWithComments</h2>--%>

        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Comment
            </th>
            </tr>
        <% foreach (var Comment in Model.Comments) { %>
             <td>
                <%: Comment.comment1%>
            </td>
        <% } %>
        </table>
            <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add Comment</legend>        

        <div class="editor-label">
        <"label">
        What to do here????????
                <%--<%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comments[0].comment1) %>--%>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Comments.comment1)%>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comments[0].comment1)%>
            </div>
        What to do here????????                        
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>

    <% } %>
    </fieldset>
    <p>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Search", "Search") %>
    </p>

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"What to do here"

You need a form:

```
<form action="/ControlerName/AddComment" method="POST">
   ...
   <%: Html.TextBox("CommentToAdd")%>
   <%: Html.Hidden("PostIdToAddComment")%>
   <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

In controller you save your comment to DB, then redirect back to the original action that will display the page, and so the comment should show up assuming you are querying the database for all comments:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddComment(string commentToAdd, int postIdToAddComment)
{
   //do your database stuff here to add comment
   return RedirectToAction("DataWithCommentsOrWhateverTheNameOfTheActionIsForTheOriginalPage")
}
```

Comment: My mistake, posted some Razor in there I'm so used to doing that.  Edited to show proper form tag.